# Solr data import with multiple matching rows only imports first row

Tags: solr, lucene, dataimporthandler

My solr data import config.xml looks something like this

```
<document>
      <entity name="users" pk="id"
         query="select id, user_name, site_id from users"
         deltaQuery = "select id from users where updated &gt;= '${dataimporter.last_index_time}'"
         deltaImportQuery = "select id, user_name, site_id from users where id = ${dataimporter.delta.id}">
         <field column="id" name="id"/>
         <field column="name" name="user_name"/>
         <field column="site_id" name="site_id"/>
         <entity name="prefs" pk="id"
               query="select pref_value from user_preferences where user_id = '${users.id}'"
               deltaQuery="select id from user_preferences where updated &gt;= '${dataimporter.last_index_time}'"
               parentDeltaQuery="select user_id as id from user_preferences where id = ${prefs.id}">
            <field column="pref_value" name="pref_value" />
         </entity>
      </entity>
   </document>
```

Where each user can have multiple preferences. Right now it only imports the first user_preference it finds. How can I import all the user preferences?

Answer (score 1):

1. make sure is pref_value a multiValued field in your schema.xml
2. I don-t think you can use parentDeltaQuery and deltaQuery in the inner entity, those are just for the parent one.

Comment: Your 2-st item, seems true according to my test, even though I didn't found any description in solr document ...